# Serve a Parcel app subfolder as static files in express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, parceljs

I have a simple app (no frameworks) bundled with Parcel that I want to serve with express.
I have divided the app in three different subfolders "assets", "pages" and "admin" so I have a similar structure to this:

```
src
  |
  --assets
  --admin
        |
        -- admin-folder
                      |
                      --index.html 
  --pages
        |
        --pages-folder
                     |
                     --index.html
```

Once the app is built and bundled with Parcel I want to serve both folders with two different express.static middlewares like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "pages"));
app.use("/admin", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "admin"));
```

I am not serving the whole "dist" folder because I wanted a cleaner URL without a "/pages" in the middle (eg. mywebsite.com/pages-folder and not mywebsite.com/pages/pages-folder) and because I can then authorize the access to the "/admin" part of the website.
But, by doing so the bundle is broken since every reference (for example to the assets) is incorrect. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I am currently running two different parcel build commands one for the pages folder, that has a --dist-dir = dist/pages and one for the admin folder (--dist-dir = dist/admin), but I'd rather use one single parcel build if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could write a [custom namer plugin](https://parceljs.org/plugin-system/namer/) to control the structure of the `dist` folder (see, for example, my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900160/how-to-handle-output-files-in-parcel/69543953#69543953)), I think that the approach you are taking of simply running parcel multiple times with different entries is probably simpler.

You can improve things further by specifiying the multiple entries in your `package.json` as different [targets](https://parceljs.org/features/targets/#package.json%23targets.*.source). That way you can build everything at once with a single call to the `parcel build` CLI command.

For example, if you had two source `.html` pages at `src/pages/index.html` and `src/admin/index.hml`, your `package.json` file might look like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "targets": {
    "pages": {
      "source": "src/pages/index.html",
      "distDir": "dist/pages"
    },
    "admin": {
      "source": "src/admin/index.html",
      "distDir": "dist/admin"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "parcel build",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.0.1",
  }
}
```

Which would generate output at `/dist/pages/index.html` and `/dist/admin/index.html`.

Comment: The solution you provided in package.json works perfectly. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

#### This solution works:

The `.proxyrc.js`

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const express = require('express');

const static_server = express();
static_server.use(express.static('.'));
var socket = static_server.listen(0);

var url = "http://127.0.0.1:" + socket.address().port + "/";
console.log(url)

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
      createProxyMiddleware("/public", {
        target: url,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/public": "/public",
        },
      })
  );
};
```

Then we can put `test.txt` into './public' folder and fetch from 'http://127.0.0.1:1234/public/test.txt'

#### Note:

The '.proxyrc.js' won't print any error even if invalid character, so you may try to create another file like 'test1.js' with 'express()' and copy these code into '.proxyrc.js'

I had tried this one before but failed: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3407#issuecomment-792394100